# Move static parts of Vue code from methods() to <template>

Tags: vue.js

Within my code there is some static data like `const YAMAP_KEY` and `let src` in the `<script>` section. I'd like to move those to the `<template>` section leaving the rest of the `<script>` section as is it now. How do I do it?

```
<template>
  <div class='some-container container'>
    <div id='yaMap'></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({

  }),
  methods: {
    loadYamap() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const YAMAP_KEY = 'abcdef';
          const YamapNode = document.createElement('script');
          let src = 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat&apikey=' + YAMAP_KEY;
          YamapNode.src = src;

          YamapNode.onload = () => resolve();
          YamapNode.onerror = (err) => {
            console.log('map didn't load');
            reject(err);
          };  
          this.$el.appendChild(YamapNode);
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadYamap()
      .then(() => {
        ymaps.ready(() => {
          var Yamap = new ymaps.Map('yaMap', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
          })
        })
      })
      .catch(ex => console.log('map load exception:', ex));
  }
}
</script>
```

UP.
I've tried adding consts to the `<template>` section.

```
 <template>
  <div class='some-container container'>
    <div id='yaMap'></div>
    <script ref='myref'>
      console.log('script in template');
      const YAMAP_KEY = '8972y3uihfiuew';
      let src = 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat';
    <script>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then accessing them in the `<script>` section.

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({

  }),
  methods: {
    loadYamap() {
      this.$refs.myref.onload = () => console.log('script in template loaded');
...
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've add an up to the post. Please take a look at it.

Comment: And what is the intent of doing this? Moving code from script to template..

Comment: Store the static data in not `<script>`. For the bigger part it is out of curiosity how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a  tag inside  and declare var for those constants and access them in your javascript code.

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="container" placeholder="enter text" v-model="value">
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
  <script>var a = 'manu';</script>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.11.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>

  new Vue({
    el: '#container',
    data: {
      value: '',
    },
    created: function() {
      console.log('Value', a);
    }
  });

</script>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/mnbhardwaj888/pen/PooPyjV